# VSCode: typescript/intellisense not responding to an auto-generated files

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsserver

I have a problem with vscode: if a file is changed externally (not by a vscode), intellisense/typechecking is not responding immediately to a change. Sometimes it works after few seconds, sometimes not - I need to open changed file in vscode or run `Restart extension host`).

I'm generating some files with a node script, and occasionally new version causes type errors, that shows immediately in webpack but not in vscode.

Is there a way to, I don't know, clear some cache, restart extension host via node.js script or somehow broadcast information about changed files?

// EDIT:
OK, So I've found out about https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html

```json
    "typescript.tsserver.watchOptions": {
        // Use native file system events for files and directories
        "watchFile": "useFsEvents",
        "watchDirectory": "useFsEvents",
    }
```

Now it works much faster (on windows) but, [according to a node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#caveats):

> **Caveats**
>
> The fs.watch API is not 100% consistent across platforms, and
> is unavailable in some situations.
>
> The recursive option is only supported on macOS and Windows. An
> `ERR_FEATURE_UNAVAILABLE_ON_PLATFORM` exception will be thrown when the
> option is used on a platform that does not support it.
>
> On Windows, no events will be emitted if the watched directory is
> moved or renamed. An `EPERM` error is reported when the watched
> directory is deleted.

Sooo.. yeah.

Comment: Running "Restart TS server" also works, and might be faster. But it's not a solution to this annoying issue.